# Display multiple lines within a Jlist cell

Tags: java, swing

How can I display multiple lines within a single cell of a JList. In jtable, it is achieved by adding a JTextarea to the table cell renderer. Similiarly, Is there any code to add a custom cell renderer for a JList that holds a textarea? If yes, can you please give me a code snippet for the same?

Or do you think there is any other better method to display multiple lines within the cell of Jlist instead of using a textarea? please help me!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem displaying components of JList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631048/problem-displaying-components-of-jlist)

Comment: please simply _do_ it: it's exactly the same mechanics as for a TableCellRenderer. If you did and experienced any problems, come back with the concrete question as to what doesn't work as you expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beside usage of [HTML code in Swing component](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) (like [Jigar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632901/display-multiple-lines-within-a-jlist-cell/5632935#5632935) says), you can also specify a [`ListCellRenderer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) that uses a TextArea, exactly like you do in your JTable.

Answer (score 3):

Try with html.

```
"line one <br/> linetwo"
```

Comment: Remember to wrap your HTML with <html> tags: "<html>line one <br/>linetwo</html>" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070484/can-items-in-a-jlist-be-formatted-as-html